# Tolerance for equality in GAMS/CPLEX

Tags: cplex, gams

Is there an option in GAMS that sets the tolerance for declaring two real numbers to equal?

For example, how can I tell GAMS or GAMS/CPLEX that $0.999100 = 0.99909$?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. To add @Mark L. Stone said, GAMS has an option to set decimals of numbers. You could try (E.g. option decimals = 4;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/S_CPLEX.html

> eprhs (real): feasibility tolerance
>
> Feasibility tolerance. This specifies the degree to which a problem's basic  variables may violate their bounds. This tolerance
> influences the selection of an optimal basis and can be reset to a
> higher value when a problem is having difficulty maintaining
> feasibility during optimization. You may also wish to lower this
> tolerance after finding an optimal solution if there is any doubt that
> the solution is truly optimal. If the feasibility tolerance is set too
> low, Cplex may falsely conclude that a problem is infeasible.
>
> Range: [1e-009, 0.1]
>
> Default: 1e-006

I believe this tolerance applies to assessing feasibility of bound, inequality, and equality constraints.